# python setup.py bdist_egg Not Setting Up Requirements for Package

Tags: python, pylons, setuptools, egg

I have a Pylons app that I am ready to deploy for the first time to production. It has a simple set of requirements listed in setup.py:

```
install_requires=[
    "Pylons>=1.0",
    "Jinja2",
    "couchdb",
    "python-openid",
],
```

When I run "python setup.py bdist_egg" it seems to create the egg file properly. When I copy the egg file to my production virtual environment and install it, however, none of my dependencies are installed. I unzipped the egg file and found that, indeed, there is no requires.txt inside. There is definitely a requires.txt that was created in the .egg-info directory when I ran bdist_egg. Am I runnning this command incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging and searching, it seems that *something* was wrong with the .egg-info directory that was in place, though I don't know what nor how it got that way. Deleting that directory and then regenerating it with the egg_info command fixed things right up.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem turned out to be wrong case, on a case insensitive file system (Mac OS X, HFS+). The directory was called munkireport.egg-info, while the name in setup.py was MunkiReport. Renaming it to the correct case fixed it.